# Difference beetween "Visual development server" and "Local IIS web server"

Tags: asp.net, iis

I just start learning MVC and i found few tutorials, when someone has changed server "Visual development server" to "Local IIS web server". Is there any difference in creating web site beetwen this two servers ?. I'am asking, beacuse when i change visual development server to Local IIS and press "start debbuing", i'am receaving message error "port 80 is already use". I checked that, and port 80 is using by "NT Kernel & System", and I completely dont know, how to change that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS is a web-server where you can host your applications. Applications is always hosting on a specified port. If port is in use, you will receive this error. You can use it for development.

Local IIS web server - is an ordinary IIS but on your local machine :)

VS dev server is a web-server integrated into Visual Studio, it is used only for development purposes.

Comment: So, there is nothing to worry about ? :)